# How can I get the product attributes with GraphQL without knowing them?

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, graphql

I have a shop with several products and each product have his own attributes. I'm trying to get those attribute values of each product with GraphQL but I don't know what are the attributes. I want to make a query that returns all the products and each product have his attributes specified. Is there a way to make that?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst listing the attributes for a given attribute set is obviously important, I had to use a Rest API call to gather the attributes.

I advise to run a Rest API (http://magento-root/index.php/rest/V1/products/attribute-sets/attributeSetId/attributes) to gather your attributes.. You might want to do this when your system loads and then cache it?

then, a query like the below will give you the products data with the attributes relevant to your attribute set.

http://magento-root/index.php/graphql

```
{
  products(
    filter: { sku: { eq: "24-WB01" } }
  ) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      color
      description {
        html
      }
      sleeve
      attribute_set_id

    }
  }
}
```